# What is the API for new Lens features in the Ubuntu TV alpha?

Tags: unity, application-development, lenses, ubuntu-tv

As of the Ubuntu 12.04 alpha, lenses are simply lists of results pushed onto a DBus domain like `net.launchpad.Lens.MyLens`. This makes lenses and scopes more or less equivalent to search engines.

However, lenses as seen in the CES Ubuntu TV demo seem to provide a visual formatting language for sets of data and operations.

[image: Screenshot of TV Guide lens]

[image: Screenshot of Movie Details lens]

Is there an API for using these awesome new lens types? Will it be available in mainline Ubuntu in the near future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this was a demo only, the APIs have not been created yet.  Join the ~ubuntu-tv team on Launchpad, and #ubuntu-tv on freenode to be a part of the conversation when these APIs and others start being made.